# Setting registers using a one-hot signal

Tags: verilog, hdl

I have a set of registers : `reg [7:0] dataRegs [3:0]` and I have a one-hot signal: `reg [3:0] oneHot`. I want to write a value to just the register indicated by the one-hot signal. So if `oneHot` = 4'b0010, that would write to `dataRegs[2]`. What would be the best way to do that?

So to read from a specific register, I have tri-state buffers as follows:

```
for (i=0; i<4; i++) begin
  output = oneHot[i]?dataRegs[i]:'bz;
end
```

But, I'm not sure how I could use the same `oneHot` signal to also write to this register. I'm wondering if there is a way to avoid converting `oneHot` to a binary number just to index into the reg array. Could I do something using a write enable for the registers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When i=0, write only to reg[0].  When i=1, write only to reg[1], etc.

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
    for (i=0; i<4; i++) begin
        if (oneHot[i]) dataRegs[i] <= wdata;
    end 
end
```